# How does the Blender User select random linked components of a Single Mesh?

Tags: selection-tools

**Goal**

In [edit mode] this Blender user would like to select random connected components.  Does this feature already exist in Blender? If yes, what are the steps?  Thanks.

**Context**

If Python is used, then a list of one vertex in every Connected Component is fine. Perhaps the lowest numbered vertex. Vertex selection from a list is relatively simple.  Blender has select linked once a vertex is selected.

Component means selectable in Blender by the concept of Blender Select Linked.  Many references would call this a connected component.  Blender API users may use the word island. Connected Component, Linked, Island seem to be alternatives.

The menu choice [**select random**] feature is readily available in Blender. It can work in either edit mode or object mode. The [**select random**] almost does what I want. The general concept of random selection by linked component is what I want for some task, not artistic selection.

Suppose a Blender single mesh contains N mesh primitives such as spheres. N is a number large enough to be time consuming for manual labor .   In the vein of  the provided random select, I would like to select some random percentage of linked components, connected components.

**Substitute**

Manual Elided steps. Create a collection.  Put Mesh in it.  Separate by loose parts. Select all in collection. Use built in random select/deselect in object mode.  Join.  Select the other items.  Join.  Result is one original mesh is now two meshes.

**Potential Substitute**

Python Script

[image]